# Geometrical description of canonical commutation relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, geometry, phase-space

Does there exist any geometrical description of canonical commutation relation of quantum mechanics $$[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar$$

maybe in phase space?

What I meant by geometry is along the lines that since commutator along with normalization condition leads to the discretization of energy of a bound system so does there exist some kind of phase space representation like [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BggT4.jpg) which would tell me why and how exactly using the CCR actually leads to the discretization of energy? Also, I would like to avoid going for Wigner representation because if I remember correctly we have commutating functions in WR when plotting phase space? And while we're at it does the phase space of a quantum system has to do anything with connes noncommutative geometry since $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ do not commute so we cannot do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqDlK.png) as we do in classical mechanics?

Comment: Hi aitfel. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic sorry, I didn't know the procedure to reopen(number of votes) the question so I made this mess.

Comment: No problem. We all learn as we go.